# how can I use both Color and Alpha for the ColorRamp

Tags: node-editor

How can I use both the Color and Alpha from the ColorRamp node so that the material output uses the color and becomes transparent?
I tried inserting a Mix Shader and connecting the ColorRamp alpha to that but it didn't work.. 
Thanks :)

[image: screenshot of node setup]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have the alpha properly control the transparency of the volume you need to multiply it into the *density* before plugging it into the strength of the emission shader.

[image]
*Click to enlarge*